# Memory issue in android using ImageView

Tags: java, android, memory, imageview

I'm really new to android .. I'm trying to display some ImageViews in a ScrollView.

```
final ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView (this);
imageView1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
imageView1.setImageResource(resourceId);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lyp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(0*dp), 1.0f);
linearLayout.addView(imageView1, lyp2);
```

My images are 766*1344px and about 300ko.

I get the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error while trying to display more than 1  differents images. It works fine using 10 times the same image.

What should I do ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the resolution of the image to be that high if you are displaying 10 images. They are likely being displayed much smaller than that resolution since they all have to fit on the screen at once. The trick is to show a lower resolution (scaled down) version of the image that fits the UI element that contains it, then only load the full res image if you need to actually show it at that size.

Read these docs for more info: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I have tryied your solution. It doesn't crash anymore but the images aren't displayed correctly .. (only shading of white and red .. strange). The only one solution which works is to create a drawable-xxxhdpi folder into the res folder and put all my images in ..